# Refreshing ListView with new data in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a function in which when a folder is clicked in listview it would display the list of files inside that folder in the same activity . ie refreshing the same listview with different data. I have built a directory like structure in database and getting the list of files and folders from their.

```
public class SkydriveFolderList extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<String> filelist1=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> filepath=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> isfolder=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> fileid=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ListView lv;
    EditText et;
    ArrayAdapter<SearchResults> arrayAdapter;
    Button back;
    TextView path;![enter image description here][1]

    public void onCreate(Bundle SkydriveFolderList)
    {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        filelist1 = i.getStringArrayListExtra("FileList");
        filepath = i.getStringArrayListExtra("FilePath");
        isfolder = i.getStringArrayListExtra("isFolder");
        fileid = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("FileId");

        super.onCreate(SkydriveFolderList);
        ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();

        setContentView(R.layout.filelist);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.skydrive_list);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        path=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.filepath);
        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<SearchResults>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,searchResults);
        // ((ListView) arrayAdapter).setAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults)); 
        //lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // When user changed the Text
            SkydriveFolderList.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()

    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {

       Object o = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
       SearchResults fullObject = (SearchResults)o;
      // prestationEco str=(prestationEco)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),fullObject.getFilename(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        });


}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCIsr.png

Please check the above link to see the snapshot of the app.

Now in that,when the document folder is clicked , the listview should be refreshed with the list of files inside that folder. How should i do it ?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged()
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself. call the method on the adapter

Comment: If the whole data is getting changed, you might have to set the adapter again with a different dataset. One  more thing, why you are storing info in database? using FileManager, you get all required details right out of the Android framework.

Comment: Define a filter in your Adapter and refresh the content with notifyDataSetChanged in your Filter.([example](http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/07/arrayadapte-filtering-and-you/))

Comment: I am using Skydrive API to get  metadata of the files and folders and storing it in database in directory like structure.

Comment: @Prannoy, did you define a custom filter in your Adapter?

Comment: No.......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user click on the list view insted of refreshing the whole listview you can call   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` this will refresh your view without any lag or crash....this will be a better meathod for you..Hope this will help.

Comment: If this answer is useful please upvote the answer.Happy to help you...:-)