# Refreshing android app

Tags: java, android

i have an android app that gets data from mysql database, now i want to implement refreshing capabilities such that when new entry is entered int the database then everyone having the app will be able to see the new entry after sometimes even without restarting the app again. how can i do that.?

i have tried to use

```
Intent i = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

but it does not do what i want as it refresh the activity but does not load new entries.

Comment: you just put the refersh button and on clicking on that you just add your calling the service of getting data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the code to fetch the new data from the db and update the entries in your `onResume()` method of this activity for your code to work.

If by entries, you are using a `ListView`, you could also use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the data without having to finish and restart the entire activity. (Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569141/refreshing-listview-with-new-data-in-android?rq=1))

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you will be calling a API to get data from mysql Database. Now you need to call that API after a fixed interval of time to get data from mysql database again.

If new entry is added into the database you need to send push notification to all users about the updation. You can also implement automatic refresh when such notification is received by the users.